# How to stretch font height wise using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Can we increase font height wise on a web page??

I have tried scale property but not getting any perfect solution for this.

Comment: How come you want to stretch the font height?

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve] of what you tired

Comment: Thanks Buddy it working with some conditions if I applied...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this:**

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 32px;
  transform: scale(.5, 1);
}
```

```html
<p>This is text.</p>
```